# DLL Programming issue

Tags: .net, dll

I have a DLL which is used to connect to a hardware device and perform various hardware functions. I decompiled the DLL file using .NET Reflector to see how it interact with the device. There is function ***GetEnrollData1*** but even after a lot of research I am unable to find the exact definition of that function. It seems to be calling itself. I am not too familier with .NET so I am providing the code here and also the link for the DLL files.

Files Can be dowload from Here: 
http://webprotechnologies.com/demo/dll.zip

Function definition I have found so far:

```
public virtual bool GetEnrollData1(int dwMachineNumber, int dwEnrollNumber, int dwBackupNumber, ref int dwMachinePrivilege, ref int dwEnrollData, ref int dwPassWord)
{
    if (this.ocx == null)
    {
        throw new AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException("GetEnrollData1", AxHost.ActiveXInvokeKind.MethodInvoke);
    }
    return this.ocx.GetEnrollData1(dwMachineNumber, dwEnrollNumber, dwBackupNumber, ref dwMachinePrivilege, ref dwEnrollData, ref dwPassWord);
}
```

Comment: It is a call into an ActiveX control.  A completely different DLL and almost certainly not capable of being decompiled since it was written in a non-.NET language.  Contact the owner of the DLL for support, you are not going to find him here.

Comment: I have the whole SDK with me but I am not able to find that specific DLL. Will it help if I share it with you guys?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to download dll due to restriction in network at my end, 
but as per my understanding it is not calling itself, but it is calling function of ocx object(defined in type of ocx class,here ocx is instance of some class, and that some class contains the definition of GetEnrollData1 called in the last line.) and it is called internally,so tried to find type of ocx in your Refactored code and then try to understand the code.